# Eigenvectors to transformation matrix

Tags: python, numpy

The following are my eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

```
(array([2.10968950e+08, 1.34010152e+07, 1.29648732e+06]),
 matrix([[-0.55967132, -0.66160005,  0.49905249],
         [-0.55140969, -0.15224734, -0.82022442],
         [-0.61863993,  0.73423847,  0.2796042 ]]))
```

How do I go about creating a 3x3 transformation matrix where the rows of the transformation matrix consist of the three normalized eigenvectors sorted from largest to smallest eigenvalues.

Comment: The matrix that you show already satisfies both requirements. It is not clear what _else_ you want to accomplish.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html